# Function to downsample dataset not working for txt files

Tags: python, pandas

I attempted to make a `function` that down-sample a dataset because sometimes the dataset becomes large and hard to handle.

```py
import pandas as pd

def DownSampler(pre_filename, post_filename, dsfactor):
    """
    DownSampler    is a function that downsamples huge datasets in order for it to be easier to handle.
    Parameters:
    pre_filename   is the name of the orginal file that is to be downsampled.
    post_filename  is the name of downsampled file.
    dsfactor       is the downsampling factor 
    Return(s):
    df_ds_xlsx     is converted to a csv-file and subsequently returned.
    df_ds_csv      is converted to a Excel-file and subsequently returned.
    """
    if '.xlsx' in pre_filename and post_filename:
        df_og_xlsx = pd.read_excel(pre_filename)
        df_ds_xlsx = df_og_xlsx.iloc[::dsfactor,:]
        return df_ds_xlsx.to_excel(post_filename)
    elif '.txt' in pre_filename and post_filename:
        df_og_csv = pd.read_csv(pre_filename)
        df_ds_csv = df_og_csv.iloc[::dsfactor,:]
        return df_ds_csv.to_csv(post_filename)
    else:
        raise ValueError('The file must either be in xlsx or csv (txt) format.')
```

It works for `Excel` files

```py
test_1 = lvdts = DownSampler('original_data_1.xlsx', 'dwnsamp_data_1.xlsx', dsfactor=12)
```

But if I try with `txt` files

```py
test_2 = lvdts = DownSampler('original_data_2.txt', 'dwnsamp_data_2.txt', dsfactor=12)
```

I get an error that says `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 112: invalid start byte`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like your text file is encoded differently. You need to find out what encoding that is, and specify it for the `read_csv` function.

Comment: Thank you, @molybdenum42. I added an `encoding` argument to `pd.read_csv`, and thus it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion from @molybdenum42, I added `encoding='iso-8859-1'` to `pd.read_csv`:

```
df_og_csv = pd.read_csv(pre_filename, encoding='iso-8859-1)
```

It now works as expected with the files I have tested it with.

Thank you, @molybdenum42!